# Iframe background color in Google Chrome

Tags: iframe, google-chrome, background

For reference so that you know what I'm talking about:
http://www.webbuddies.co.za/Pages/Portfolio.aspx

In Google Chrome, the `<iframe>` doesn't take it's background color from the site linked in it's `src` attribute, but instead from the parent page's background.

It works 100% perfectly in IE and FF, but how do I get it to display right in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

The style attribute of your iframe says background:none. Remove this inline css and it should work.

Comment: no, I put that there trying to fix it. It made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the color of the linked site's body background , "#fff" eg.